# Sklearn preprocessing - PolynomialFeatures - How to keep column names/headers of the output array / dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, scikit-learn, cross-validation

TLDR: **How to get headers for the output numpy array from the sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures() function?**

---

Let's say I have the following code...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing as pp

a = np.ones(3)
b = np.ones(3) * 2
c = np.ones(3) * 3

input_df = pd.DataFrame([a,b,c])
input_df = input_df.T
input_df.columns=['a', 'b', 'c']

input_df

    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1   1   2   3
2   1   2   3

poly = pp.PolynomialFeatures(2)
output_nparray = poly.fit_transform(input_df)
print output_nparray

[[ 1.  1.  2.  3.  1.  2.  3.  4.  6.  9.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.  3.  1.  2.  3.  4.  6.  9.]
 [ 1.  1.  2.  3.  1.  2.  3.  4.  6.  9.]]
```

How can I get that 3x10 matrix/ output_nparray to carry over the a,b,c labels how they relate to the data above?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Working example, all in one line (I assume "readability" is not the goal here):

```
target_feature_names = ['x'.join(['{}^{}'.format(pair[0],pair[1]) for pair in tuple if pair[1]!=0]) for tuple in [zip(input_df.columns,p) for p in poly.powers_]]
output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_nparray, columns = target_feature_names)
```

> **Update**: as @OmerB pointed out, now you can use the `get_feature_names` [method](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.get_feature_names):

```
>> poly.get_feature_names(input_df.columns)
['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a^2', 'a b', 'a c', 'b^2', 'b c', 'c^2']
```

Answer (score 37):

scikit-learn 0.18 added a nifty [`get_feature_names()`](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.get_feature_names) method!

```
>> input_df.columns
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

>> poly.fit_transform(input_df)
array([[ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  9.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  9.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  6.,  9.]])

>> poly.get_feature_names(input_df.columns)
['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a^2', 'a b', 'a c', 'b^2', 'b c', 'c^2']
```

Note you have to provide it with the columns names, since sklearn doesn't read it off from the DataFrame by itself.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
def PolynomialFeatures_labeled(input_df,power):
    '''Basically this is a cover for the sklearn preprocessing function. 
    The problem with that function is if you give it a labeled dataframe, it ouputs an unlabeled dataframe with potentially
    a whole bunch of unlabeled columns. 

    Inputs:
    input_df = Your labeled pandas dataframe (list of x's not raised to any power) 
    power = what order polynomial you want variables up to. (use the same power as you want entered into pp.PolynomialFeatures(power) directly)

    Ouput:
    Output: This function relies on the powers_ matrix which is one of the preprocessing function's outputs to create logical labels and 
    outputs a labeled pandas dataframe   
    '''
    poly = pp.PolynomialFeatures(power)
    output_nparray = poly.fit_transform(input_df)
    powers_nparray = poly.powers_

    input_feature_names = list(input_df.columns)
    target_feature_names = ["Constant Term"]
    for feature_distillation in powers_nparray[1:]:
        intermediary_label = ""
        final_label = ""
        for i in range(len(input_feature_names)):
            if feature_distillation[i] == 0:
                continue
            else:
                variable = input_feature_names[i]
                power = feature_distillation[i]
                intermediary_label = "%s^%d" % (variable,power)
                if final_label == "":         #If the final label isn't yet specified
                    final_label = intermediary_label
                else:
                    final_label = final_label + " x " + intermediary_label
        target_feature_names.append(final_label)
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(output_nparray, columns = target_feature_names)
    return output_df

output_df = PolynomialFeatures_labeled(input_df,2)
output_df

    Constant Term   a^1 b^1 c^1 a^2 a^1 x b^1   a^1 x c^1   b^2 b^1 x c^1   c^2
0               1   1   2   3   1           2           3   4           6   9
1               1   1   2   3   1           2           3   4           6   9
2               1   1   2   3   1           2           3   4           6   9
```

Answer (score 1):

The `get_feature_names()` method is good, but it returns all variables as `'x1'`, `'x2'`, `'x1 x2'`, ...etc. Below is a function to quickly transform the `get_feature_names()` output to a list of column names formatted as `'Col_1'`, `'Col_2'`, `'Col_1 x Col_2'`:

IN:

```
def PolynomialFeatureNames(sklearn_feature_name_output, df):
"""
This function takes the output from the .get_feature_names() method on the PolynomialFeatures 
instance and replaces values with df column names to return output such as 'Col_1 x Col_2'

sklearn_feature_name_output: The list object returned when calling .get_feature_names() on the PolynomialFeatures object
df: Pandas dataframe with correct column names
"""
import re
cols = df.columns.tolist()
feat_map = {'x'+str(num):cat for num, cat in enumerate(cols)}
feat_string = ','.join(sklearn_feature_name_output)
for k,v in feat_map.items():
    feat_string = re.sub(fr"\b{k}\b",v,feat_string)
return feat_string.replace(" "," x ").split(',')  

interaction = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_inter = interaction.fit_transform(input_df)

names = PolynomialFeatureNames(interaction.get_feature_names(),input_df)

print(pd.DataFrame(X_inter, columns= names))
```

OUT:

```
            1       a       b       c     a^2   a x b   a x c     b^2   b x c  \
0 1.00000 1.00000 2.00000 3.00000 1.00000 2.00000 3.00000 4.00000 6.00000   
1 1.00000 1.00000 2.00000 3.00000 1.00000 2.00000 3.00000 4.00000 6.00000   
2 1.00000 1.00000 2.00000 3.00000 1.00000 2.00000 3.00000 4.00000 6.00000   

      c^2  
0 9.00000  
1 9.00000  
2 9.00000
```

Comment: This is just what I needed for plotting my features with little x's in between. Thanks. Suggested change is to use `.get_feature_names_out()` as `.get_feature_names()` is deprecated.
Also please add indentation for help with copy-and-pasters.