# Scikit-learn Imputer Reducing Dimensions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe with 332 columns. I want to impute values to be able to use scikit-learn's decision tree classifier. My problem is that the column of the resulting data from imputer function is only 330.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
cols = data.columns
new = imp.fit_transform(data)

print(data.shape,new.shape)
(34132, 332) (34132, 330)
```

Comment: Do you have all-NaN columns by any chance?

Comment: Yes. That's my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation of `sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html):

> When axis=0, columns which only contained missing values at fit are discarded upon transform.

So, this is removing all-missing-value columns.