# How to get column names from my numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I used L1-based feature selection shown [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) in order to select suitable columns from pandas DataFrame `X`.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

lsvc = LinearSVC(C=0.01, penalty="l1", dual=False).fit(X, y)
model = SelectFromModel(lsvc, prefit=True)
X_new = model.transform(X)
```

However it is not clear to me how can I get the column names. Since `X_new` is `numpy` array, I tried this:

```
X_new.dtype.names
```

But it returns nothing. So, how can I actually understand which columns have been selected?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/29907472/4764434?

Comment: @Zero: In my case the number of features is not equal in the original X and X_new. I saw this solution, but I do not understand what is "feature_selector.get_support": `X_selected_df = pd.DataFrame(X_new, columns=[X.columns[i] for i in range(len(X.columns)) if feature_selector.get_support()[i]])`

Comment: This is what I tried: `X_selected_df = pd.DataFrame(X_new, columns=[X.columns[i] for i in range(len(X.columns)) if SelectFromModel.get_support()[i]])`, but got `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'`.

Comment: Are you using a csv data file?

Comment: No, I am using `iris = load_iris()`. No csv.

Comment: try using a csv file so that you can do `pd.read_csv`

Comment: @LiamHealy: Ok, now I have this error: `TypeError: get_support() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: I solved it. I had to use `model.get_support` instead of `SelectFromModel.get_support`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have converted your data into a csv file, you will want to use `pd.read_csv` to get that file into a dataframe.

You can then use the `columns` attribute to access the columns.

Furthermore, you could use the `to_list` attribute to get the columns as a list.

Alternatively, you could use Ahmad's method:

```
import re

f = open('f.csv','r')

alllines = f.readlines()
columns = re.sub(' +',' ',alllines[0]) #delete extra space in one line
columns = columns.strip().split(',') #split using space

print(columns)
```

EDIT: The question was solved by the OP through using `model.get_support` instead of `SelectFromModel.get_support`