# Identify features removed by SimpleImputer

Tags: python, dataframe, sklearn-pandas, feature-detection, imputation

I used SimpleImputer on my dataframe, which obviously contained some NaN (as a result of ohe) because the number of features before the imputation was larger than that after it.

Is there any way I can find out which features were removed? I did specify verbose =1 in my imputation code...

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `features_specs_train_ohe = pd.get_dummies(features_specs_train)`
    `imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = 'median', verbose=1)`
    
    `feaures_specs_train_ohe = imputer.fit_transform(feaures_specs_train_ohe)`

`feaures_specs_train_ohe.shape` before the imputation was (1001, 1523) and after imputation is (1001, 1447)

Comment: There are some possible solution in the comments from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586323/how-to-retain-column-headers-of-data-frame-after-pre-processing-in-scikit-learn) by @selwyth.