# Retaining Headings after Nomalizing using sklearn Normalizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I am trying to normalize a dataset using min- max normalizer.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
x = df1.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
```

Inupt

```
PID | FNID | ID
-----------------
10  | 15   | 20
11  | 16   | 21
```

Expected Output

```
PID | FNID |ID
---------------
0.1 | 0.15 | 0.2
0.11| 0.16 | 0.21
```

But I am getting output like..

```
0   | 1    | 2
----------------
0.1 | 0.15 | 0.2
0.11| 0.16 |0.21
```

I want the headers as in the original dataset. I tried [This.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586323/how-to-retain-column-headers-of-data-frame-after-pre-processing-in-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 0):

I tried.

```
x = df1.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df11 = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled, columns = df1.columns)
df11.head()
```

And got expected result.

Thank you!