# Combine two Histograms into one with different X and Y value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, histogram

I have 2 dataframes. I make every `df` plot histogram looks like this:

```
df1
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
df2
plt.show()
```

[image]

if possible, I want to combine and show these histogram in single histogram but side by side with the different value. Is it possible?. my expected output looks like this [Multiple Histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-at-the-same-time-with-matplotlib) (Example):

```
df_example
plt.show()
```

[image]

please give me advise.

Comment: working but my two histograms have different x and y value, one histogram too big and one to small result

Comment: you could try scaling or normalising the series before applying

Comment: how to do that? Forgive me because of I am newbie in python, thank you

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414913/normalize-columns-of-pandas-data-frame/29651514.

it will give you a idea to solve your problem. once you apply the normalisation data will lies between 0 to 1 or -1 to 1. so your data is scaled. you could use this in histogram

Comment: thank you in advance, I'll try this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,4,2,1,43,23,12,54,12,344,45,212,12,43]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"b":[223,234,234,342,652,234,652,121,345,456,234,467,234,568,237]})
plt.hist([df1['a'],df2['b']], color = ['b','g'],label=['a','b'])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: how to add legend between this two histogram, example green (A) and blue (B)?