# colour map grids based on value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cartopy

I want to fill the gridded map with colors based on the value of interest. A sample data is here:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['lon'] = [100,105,110,115,120,125,130]
df['lat'] = [38,40,42,44,46,48,50]
df['value'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Specifically, is it possible to do this with `Cartopy`? I found a similar question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412785/plotting-pandas-csv-data-onto-cartopy-map. But that post was to plot scattered points, I need to fill the grids with colors.

I myself tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(df['lon'], df['lat'])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[15,15])
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.pcolormesh(lon,lat,df['variable'],latlon=True,cmap='jet')

plt.show()
```

The error is at `ax.pcolormesh(...)`, it says `"not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"`

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: But your grid is not continuous. What's your expectation from the included data?

Comment: Yes, the grids may not always be continuous. The real work behind this sample is the satellite observations, which has random data gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For discrete data you can create rectangular patches for each point. Here is a possible solution for your sample data set. Each row of data (lat, long, value) is used to create a rectangular patch. The `value` is normalized by dividing with max(value) to enable using colormap for coloring the patches.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

def make_rect(clon, clat, dlon, dlat):
    lon_min = clon - dlon/2.
    lat_min = clat - dlat/2.
    lon_max = clon + dlon/2.
    lat_max = clat + dlat/2.
    # clockwise from LL
    #lons = [lon_min, lon_min, lon_max, lon_max, lon_min]
    #lats = [lat_min, lat_max, lat_max, lat_min, lat_min]
    ll = [lon_min,lat_min]
    ul = [lon_min,lat_max]
    ur = [lon_max,lat_max]
    lr = [lon_max,lat_min]
    return [ll, ul, ur, lr, ll]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['lon'] = [100,105,110,115,120,125,130]
df['lat'] = [38,40,42,44,46,48,50]
df['value'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]   # not suffice for meshgrid plot

# The colormap to use.
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8,6])
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(), extent=[95, 134, 35, 52])

# plot the red dots using the available data
# comment out if not needed
ax.plot(df['lon'], df['lat'], 'ro')

# plot rectangular patches at the data points
dlon, dlat = 5, 2  #spacings between data points
for lon1, lat1, val1 in zip(df['lon'], df['lat'], df['value']):
    pcorners = make_rect(lon1, lat1, dlon, dlat)
    poly = mpatches.Polygon(pcorners, ec='gray', fill=True, lw=0.25, \
           fc=cm(val1 / max(df['value'])), transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.add_patch(poly)       

ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]

Comment: I succeeded in applying this to my real work task! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But in this way, how can I add the colorbar? because in my codes there is one line: ```sc = ax.scatter(...); cbar = fig.colorbar(sc, cax=cbar_ax, extend=extend_subplot)```, now since ```ax``` is in the loop, and there is no ```sc``` returned back...