# While normalizing the data in python, getting this error:Error evaluating factor: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, normalization

My data:

```
absent_data.head()
```

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsJHa.png)

Before it was running smooth, this is my code:

```
cnames = ['Transportation expense', 'Distance from Residence to Work',
   'Service time', 'Age', 'Work load Average/day ', 'Hit target',
   'Son', 'Pet', 'Weight','Body mass index',
   'Absenteeism time in hours']

#Nomalization
for i in cnames:
    print(i)
    absent_data[i] = (absent_data[i] - min(absent_data[i]))/(max(absent_data[i]) - min(absent_data[i]))
```

### Now getting this error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         2 for i in cnames:
>         3     print(i)
>   ----> 4     absent_data[i] = (absent_data[i] - min(absent_data[i]))/(max(absent_data[i]) - min(absent_data[i]))
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

It was float before too.

Comment: what is `absent_data`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis it is my dataset.

Comment: and what do you expect to happen when doing `absent_data['Transportation expense']` for example? Because that is what you are doing..

Comment: `for i in cnames` change it to `for i in range(len(cnames)):`

Comment: what is `type(absent_data)`

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what the loop should compute? Also, please update the title of your question according to the problem it describes.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I am trying to normalize the data. In the loop, there is an equation to do it.

Comment: @RahilHastu I can't give a range as I only want those columns to include which are in the cnames. I do not want a range. type(absent_data) is pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: @nesreka oh sorry, I will add all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are assigning a float value to `min` or `max`, and `min` or `max` function is overridden. Restart your notebook & remove the overriding part, then you would get the expected result.

Otherwise, just use `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler` instead of implementing it by yourself.

[Normalize columns of pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414913/normalize-columns-of-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: The same code is working fine for another data set and there too I have float values.

Comment: Is there any line like `min = ...` or `max = ...` in your notebook? This will override the function and cause `is not callable` error.

Comment: There was min=.. max=... in my notebook, that was after normalization code. That is the reason it worked well 1st time and after running the whole code again it was giving an error. Yes, I will do it using the sklearn library. Thank you so much.