# Error while working on .csv with load_csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataset, load-csv

I am trying to work on the below **code**:

```
ds = load_csv('C:\\User.csv')
f = open(ds,'r')
lines = f.readlines()[1:]
print(lines)
f.close()
```

First line of dataset is string. I am getting the below **error**:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Though when I try to open the file with below code it **works**:

```
filename='C:\\User.csv'
f = open(filename,'r')
lines = f.readlines()[1:]
print(lines)
f.close()
```

I am ignoring the first line because its string and rest of the dataset is float.

**Update:**

load_csv

```
def load_csv(ds):
    dataset = list()
    with open(ds, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if not row:
                continue
            dataset.append(row)
            return dataset
```

Even if I use this way still get the **error**:

```
ds = load_csv('C:\\Users.csv')
minmax = dataset_minmax(ds)
normalize_dataset(ds, minmax)

def dataset_minmax(dataset):
    minmax = list()
    for i in range(len(dataset[0])):
        col_values = [row[i] for row in dataset]
        value_min = min(col_values)
        value_max = max(col_values)
        minmax.append([value_min, value_max])
    return minmax

def normalize_dataset(dataset, minmax):
    for row in dataset:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            row[i] = (row[i] - minmax[i][0]) / (minmax[i][1] - minmax[i][0])
```

It gives **error** on:

```
row[i] = (row[i] - minmax[i][0]) / (minmax[i][1] - minmax[i][0])
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: Where is the `load_csv` function from? It’s common to use pandas `read_csv` function.

Comment: Also in future, add line numbers and mention the line where you get the error!

Comment: updated with load_csv

Answer (score 0):

Since you're now getting a different error, I'll give a second answer.

This error means that the two variables in your subtraction are strings, not numbers.

```
In [1]: 5 - 3
Out[1]: 2

In [2]: '5' - '3'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4ef7506473f1> in <module>
----> 1 '5' - '3'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

This is because the CSV reader assumes everything is a string. You need to convert it to floats, e.g., by changing `load_csv` to do something like `dataset.append(list(map(float, row)))` instead of your existing append statement.

The min-max stuff doesn't fail, because Python's min and max work on strings, too:

```
In [3]: min('f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r')
Out[3]: 'a'
```

However, it might be giving you incorrect answers:

```
In [4]: min('2.0', '10.0')
Out[4]: '10.0'
```

By the way, if you're doing much along these lines, you'd probably benefit from using the [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package instead of rolling your own.

Comment: even if i change that line to dataset.append(list(map(float, row))), it still giving error 'dataset.append(list(map(float, row)))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7;0.27;0.36;20.7;0.045;45;170;1.001;3;0.45;8.8;6''

Comment: Your input data is semi-colon separated, not comma separated. CSV would have a line '7,0.27,0.36,...' instead of '7;0.27;0.36;...'. Use `delimiter=';'` when you create the CSV `reader`.

Comment: row[i] = (row[i] - minmax[i][0]) / (minmax[i][1] - minmax[i][0])
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: That's a different error. You have a row where the min and max values are the same, apparently. You might want to try printing out the intermediate data and seeing what you have. Or take advantage of other tools that exist: load it in pandas and then do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41532180/4205735

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing the error is in the `open` command in your code. The reason why this fails is that the `open` command expects a `string` or operating system path-like object that is a handle to a file that it can open (like it says in the error). The function `load_csv` probably returns a list which is an incompatible format for `open`

Comment: After your update it seems that my explanation were made with reasonable assumptions :)

Answer (score -1):

Look at your first two lines where it doesn't work:

```
ds = load_csv('C:\\User.csv')
f = open(ds,'r')
```

`ds` is an object returned (from TensorFlow, I assume?) which contains the data. Then you open it as if it were a filename. This is why the interpreter complains. `ds` is the dataset, not the string representing the file.

It works in the other example, because you use a filename.

Comment: you can delete this answer so we can work on above one