# How to normalize columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I have a pandas dataframe which has the term frequencies for corpus with the terms as rows and the years as columns like so:

```
|       | term    |   2002 |   2003 |   2004 |   2005 |
|------:|:--------|-------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
|  3708 | climate |      1 |     10 |      1 |     14 |
|  8518 | global  |     12 |     11 |      2 |     12 |
| 13276 | nuclear |     10 |      1 |      0 |      4 |
```

I would like to be able to normalize the values for each word by dividing them by the total number of words for a given year -- some years contain twice as many texts, so I trying to scale by year (like Google Books). I have looked at examples for how to scale for a single column, a la Chris Albon and I have seen examples here on SO for scaling *all* the columns, but every time I try to convert this dataframe to an array to scale, things choke on the fact that the term column isn't numbers. (I tried setting the terms column as index, but that didn't go well.) I can imagine a way to do this with a `for` loop, but almost every example of clean **pandas** code I read says not to use for loops because there's a **pandas** way of doing, well, everything.

What I would like is some way of saying:

```
for these columns [the years]:
    divide each row by the sum of all rows
```

That's it.

Comment: Do you want of a particular column or multiple columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalize columns of pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414913/normalize-columns-of-pandas-data-frame)

Comment: Thanks, @RajuBhaya. In fact, I looked at that answer, but it doesn't show a way to exclude the non-number column from the pre-processing, and, as you probably know, numpy arrays don't like text! (Along my way to asking the question above I even tried that particular code example!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
In [5]: %paste                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
cols = ['2002', '2003', '2004', '2005']
df[cols] = df[cols] / df[cols].sum()

## -- End pasted text --

In [6]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[6]: 
      term      2002      2003      2004      2005
0  climate  0.043478  0.454545  0.333333  0.466667
1   global  0.521739  0.500000  0.666667  0.400000
2  nuclear  0.434783  0.045455  0.000000  0.133333
```

Comment: Thank you both for great answers. This one got the check for being the simplest and the most pandas-like. (Or whatever the pandas equivalent of "pythonic" is.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['term', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005'],
    data=[['climate', 1, 10, 1, 14],
          ['global', 12, 11, 2, 12],
          ['nuclear', 10, 1, 0, 4], ])
normalized = df.select_dtypes('int').apply(lambda x: x / sum(x))
df = df.merge(
    right=normalized,
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    suffixes=['', '_norm']
)
```

Returns

```
      term  2002  2003  2004  2005  2002_norm  2003_norm  2004_norm  2005_norm
0  climate     1    10     1    14   0.043478   0.454545   0.333333   0.466667
1   global    12    11     2    12   0.521739   0.500000   0.666667   0.400000
2  nuclear    10     1     0     4   0.434783   0.045455   0.000000   0.133333
```

Comment: Again, my thanks for this answer. While I gave the other answer the check for being the on I decided to use, this one's use of the lambda function is something I am going to remember.