# Normalize column: sum to 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
  Time   Weight 
   1       4 
   2       2
   3       1
   4       7
```

How can I normalize the weight column, so that the sum of the values in the weight column are equal to 1 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalize columns of pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414913/normalize-columns-of-pandas-data-frame) or [Normalize columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62664042/15497888) or [Normalize data in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12525722/15497888)

Comment: The second link is helpful.. cheers @HenryEcker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can divide each values in the `Weight` column by `sum` of all the values in the `Weight` column,

```py
df['Weight']/df['Weight'].sum()

0    0.285714
1    0.142857
2    0.071429
3    0.500000
Name: Weight, dtype: float64
```