# Normalize a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, normalization

I have a dataframe with about 60 columns that I need to normalize before I can run it through a multiple regression analysis. Are there python packages that can do this? I have already seen code or answers that can achieve this but not packages.

Comment: And what's wrong with using code that is not imported from a package?

Comment: What do you mean by normalize in the first place? This word has different meanings in statistics and databases. Pandas and Numpy have several relevant functions already but you may not need even those

Comment: Why is this question not a duplicate of eg [Normalize Columns of a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414913/normalize-columns-of-a-dataframe) ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it at all. I figured a package would make sure it is done correctly as I am new to the Python analytics and I am learning my way around since the multiple regression is something I was not taught when I got my degree.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If my machine-learning spider senses are correct, I would suggest using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` in a `sklearn` `Pipeline` before feeding the data to a model. See [documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html)

This completely delegates the normalization to the `sklearn` package.