# How to create Clusters and see which Influencer performs better in python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, cluster-analysis, correlation

In my dataset I have the information of different influencers who posted on specific days and with that also the conversion of new subs they brought in. I want to see if per week the influencers who post together perform better or worse depending on how they are combined.

My dataset looks like this:

```
Influencer    Week         Conversions 
Tim           1              2
Tom           1              3
Stacey        2              2 
Tom           2              5
Michi         3              6
Tim           3              5
Stacey        3              3
Tom           4              2
Michi         4              5
```

What is the best way to analyse this and how do I cluster them in order to compare if for example Tim performs worse or better if Michi also posts that same week.

Comment: What would be the exact expected output given your example?

Answer (score 2):

This is little data to draw correlations, of course, but here would be a method:
Start with pivoting your data as a time series, then normalize activity by agent and week, finally draw correlations between activity timelines.

### Reshape data as time series

```
import pandas as pd

timeline = pd.pivot_table(data = df,
                          columns = ['Influencer'],
                          index = ['Week']).fillna(value=0)
timeline
           Conversions                 
Influencer       Michi Stacey  Tim  Tom
Week                                   
1                  0.0    0.0  2.0  3.0
2                  0.0    2.0  0.0  5.0
3                  6.0    3.0  5.0  0.0
4                  5.0    0.0  0.0  2.0
```

*It is important to [fill missing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with zeroes while [pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). Otherwise (i.e. leaving them as NaNs), you run the risk that further calculations will ignore weeks of total inactivity. Indeed, ignoring NaN is the default behaviour of .mean() or .std() in the next section.*

### Normalize the activity of each agent

Timeline, normalized:

```
TN = (timeline-timeline.mean())/timeline.std()
TN
           Conversions                              
Influencer       Michi    Stacey       Tim       Tom
Week                                                
1            -0.858956 -0.833333  0.105802  0.240192
2            -0.858956  0.500000 -0.740613  1.200961
3             1.015129  1.166667  1.375424 -1.200961
4             0.702782 -0.833333 -0.740613 -0.240192
```

More on this: [Normalize columns of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26414913/12846804)

### Calculate correlations

#### Numerical analysis

Correlations between timelines:

```
TN[conv].corr()
Influencer     Michi    Stacey       Tim       Tom
Influencer                                        
Michi       1.000000  0.294995  0.473673 -0.875274
Stacey      0.294995  1.000000  0.587788 -0.266880
Tim         0.473673  0.587788  1.000000 -0.779325
Tom        -0.875274 -0.266880 -0.779325  1.000000
```

From which we draw that, for example,

- Michi seems to have an awful interaction with Tom (-0.88). Indeed, Mitchi tends to not deliver anything while Tom is active, and vice-versa.
- As far as teamwork goes, the Tim & Stacey pair culminates at 0.59. Indeed they have their production peak the same week (week 3)

#### Graphical analysis

Alternatively, using e.g. [seaborn pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.pairplot(TN[conv],kind='kde')
```

[image: Pairwise correlations]

An upward trend signifies possible teamwork, while a downwards trend means the pair does not seem to get along well.

To go further: *beyond-pairwise* correlations, provided the total dataset is large enough.